# Birthday Problem: Why isn't the probability 253/365

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, birthday

Consider a set of $23$ unrelated people. Because each 23  pair of people shares the same birthday with probability $1/365$, and there are $\binom{23}2 = 253$ pairs, why isn’t the probability that at least two people have the same birthday equal to $253/365$?

Comment: @Tehreem Because the $253/365$ is the expected number of coincidences, but there could be more than one pair of identical birthdays so the probability is strictly smaller.  By your logic if you have $28$ people then the probability is $>1$!

Comment: $Pr(A\cup B)\neq Pr(A)+Pr(B)$.  What is true is that $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$.  You seem to have been using the logic that the event "at least one pair shares a birthday" is $\bigcup A_i$ where $A_i$ is the event that pair $i$ shares a birthday and tried to use $Pr(\bigcup A_i) = \sum Pr(A_i)$, but this is untrue since these events are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I've modified the formula to what was apparently the way the number $253$ was attained here. I've left the incomprehensible "each 23 pair" (with some non ASCII character in there) for OP to correct.

Comment: If you choose this method, then you'll need to use Inclusion/Exclusion principle (which is extremely complicated in this specific case).

Comment: This is a direct question from Sheldon Ross. If there are 23 people then what is the probability two of them will have on same day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that some two people have the same birthday. For $i < j$, let $A_{i,j}$ be the event that persons $i$ and $j$ have the same birthday. Then, $\text{Pr}(A_{i,j}) = \frac{1}{365}$, and your calculation is essentially that
$$
\sum_{1 \le i <j \le 23} \text{Pr}(A_{i,j}) = \sum_{i,j} \frac{1}{365}  = \frac{\binom{23}{2} }{365} = \frac{253}{365}.
$$
But unfortunately, $\text{Pr}(A) \ne \sum_{1 \le i <j \le 23} \text{Pr}(A_{i,j})$,
because even though $A = \bigcup_{i,j} A_{i,j}$, the events $A_{i,j}$ are NOT disjoint: **it could be that multiple pairs of people have the same birthday.**

On the other hand, the *total number* of pairs sharing a birthday is $1$ birthday for each $A_{i,j}$ that occurs; therefore the [*expected number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of pairs sharing a birthday is exactly what you have calculated:
$\sum_{1 \le i <j \le 23} \text{Pr}(A_{i,j}) = \frac{253}{365}$.

Comment: I think "(total|expected) number of birthdays" should instead be "(total|expected) number of pairs sharing a birthday".

Comment: @stewbasic You are correct. Thank you.

Comment: If there are 23 people then what is the probability two of them will have on same day?

Comment: @Tehreem that is the original birthday problem. Any of the other posts on it should have your answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks.. :)

Comment: @Tehreem ok! Glad i could help.

Comment: Just another clarification, if it was 'Probability that 2 ppl have same bday, then it would have been 253/356'? But since it is atleast 2 ppl have the same bday, hence probability will be <=253/365 ? Is this right?

Comment: @Tehreem not exactly. Those two questions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

explanation for prob 1/365
we consider one pair (a,b) of people...the sample space for a particular pair has 365*365 elements...and out of those the elemnts which have same birthday dates will be 365...so thats how the prob is 1/365....

and considering that prob for one pair is 1/365 and there are total 253 pair then there will be 253/365...is wrong beacause they are not mutually exclusive....

according to me the correct answer can be like this..
prob atleast one two people have same bdy=prob(2peoplesame)+prob(3people same)+....prob(23 people same)

=1/365+1/(365)^2 + 1/(365)^3+...1/(365)^22
=1/364(approx)

Answer (score 0):

253/365 is the expected number of pairs with the same birthday. However, you might have two or more pairs. Your formula would count that as 2, while the answer to “anybody with same birthdays” is “yes” and not “yes yes”. So your number is too high.